# Building up a robust experience system in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple experience system in Unity.

```
    public void GainExperience(float experienceToAdd) // the Player gains some XP
    {
        currentExperience += experienceToAdd; // add the XP to the current XP

        if (currentExperience > experienceNeeded) // enough XP to level up
        {
            currentExperience = currentExperience - experienceNeeded; // reset the current XP
            experienceNeededToLevelUp *= 2; // increase the needed xp for the next level
            currentLevel++; // increase the players level
            skillpoints++; // gain a skillpoint
            UpdateLevelText(); // GUI Update
        }

        UpdateXPBar(); // GUI Update
    }
```

So I think this code is not the best. When I get that much XP, that I can level up twice or more, the code will not be correct.

So how can I modify it?

Comment: why do you think your code will not be correct? and why are you using `experienceNeeded`, `info.ExperienceNeeded` and `experienceNeededToLevelUp` for the same purpose?

Comment: @AdrienLacroix sorry, I edited my code. I think it would not work because the difference will just contain one more level up. If the difference is that big, that it could contain three level ups, they would get lost in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while (currentExperience >= experienceNeeded)
{
    currentLevel++;
    skillpoints++;

    currentExperience -= experienceNeeded;
    experienceNeeded *= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an editor CurveField to get a custom progression.

[image]

Then in GainExperience() you would just have to use Evaluate() with XP as parameter to get the new level, and if it's different from the current level calling your update GUI functions.